# Open Cms: How can I insert jsp code (captcha) to flexiblecontents?

Tags: xml, jsp, opencms

I have such footer http://hydra.rs.net.ua:8180/opencms/opencms/RS. It contain element "flexiblecontents". How can I insert jsp file (captcha) to flexiblecontents (xml) and catch result?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, just follow the instruction for the captcha